# Is it possible for the FirebaseAnalytics instance in my Library project to send the tracked events into a Firebase project that isn't the app's?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a Library Project consisting of a single Activity with various fragments and helper classes.

I have FirebaseAnalytics put inside this library project, put in its own helper class. The instance in that helper class was retrieved using the code:

```
private val firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(LibInterface.getInstance().srcApp)
```

As can be inferred from the code, I'm using the source application's `Application` instance to get the instanceof the `FirebaseAnalytics` used in the library project.

This source application also uses its own `FirebaseAnalytics` instance:

```
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
```

I'm taking a guess that both instances of `FirebaseAnalytics` would be the exact same, and that they would both be sending tracked events into the App's Firebase project.

Is it possible to send the events tracked in the library project into a separate Firebase project by getting the `FirebaseAnalytics` instance using the context of the sole Activity inside the Library project, and do I need a library-level `google-services.json` for that?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible.  Analytics works per-app, not per-library.  There is currently no way for a library to redirect analytics information to a different project than the one that was used as the default for the app.  This is important to make sure that each app owners understands the activity of the app in its entirety.