# How to add firebase analytics in a library?

Tags: android, module, firebase-analytics

I have created a library project(MyLibrary), this includes firebase analytics as well. Integrated this library into a separate project(SamplePorject) which has its own firebase analytics.

For firebase analytics created project(MyLibrary) from xxx account and separate project(SampleProject) from YYY account. Got 2 google-services.json files, separate keys and servers Ids etc for both and kept in both projects.

When running two projects separately, successfully logged events in both accounts.

Problem is when I have integrated MyLibrary into SampleProject, no events logged in MyLibrary account(xxx). Instead all events are logged in SampleProject account(YYY). My requirement is, events should logged in individual accounts instead of both events in single account.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior: if the application uses Firebase, all analytics data will be reported to the project that is configured in the application.

Also see:

- [Include Firebase Analytics in library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790977/include-firebase-analytics-in-library)
- [Implement Firebase inside of a Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38596093/implement-firebase-inside-of-a-library) (shows how to use Firebase for Analytics in a library, but not in the app)
- [Is it possible for the FirebaseAnalytics instance in my Library project to send the tracked events into a Firebase project that isn't the app's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52694971/is-it-possible-for-the-firebaseanalytics-instance-in-my-library-project-to-send)